# How to build binutils for a specific target

Tags: gcc, binutils, netbsd

I'm trying to configure binutils for an ARM processor, specifically the ARMv5TE.  The processor is the Marvell 88F5281.  Presently the device is running NetBSD, so I want to make sure I configure binutils for the right target arch / OS.

Is there a way to list a combination of targets / OSes when configuring binutils?

So far I found, `arm-*-netbsdelf` from the following page, http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#arm-x-eabi

But I am still wondering if there is a list of targets / OSes when I run the `configure` script from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start might be the NetBSD build.sh, which is designed to build a complete cross compiler toolset for a NetBSD target on a POSIX host.

- Download and extract the source tree for the NetBSD version your target is running
- Run './build.sh -m evbarm tools'
- When completed it should tell you where to find built binutils and cross compiler

Note - if the target is bigendian you will need to use evbarm-eb in the build.sh command.

Comment: The host OS I'm trying to build the toolchain is OS X, so are you saying install NetBSD in a VM, then build a cross compiler in the VM?

Comment: You should be able to download the NetBSD source, install OS X's Xcode and build the NetBSD cross compiler directly under OS X.

NetBSD is designed to allow you to cross build a full distribution for any NetBSD target from any POSIX box - *BSD, Linux, OS X, etc.

In this case we are only interested in the toolchain, but its simplest to download the entire tree and then just run the 'build tools' stage.

Comment: I just built the cross compile tools on a NetBSD 4.0 VM, but I still can't get a simple `Hello World` program to compile.  It errors out stating that it can't find the `stdio.h`

Comment: I'm happy to try to reproduce this end. Could you confirm what NetBSD version is on the target - 4.0?
I have a few arm boxes around (and could probably just spin up qemu to test on my laptop if I'm travelling), and I'll configure a NetBSD toolchain on my mac to reproduce

Comment: Yes, indeed the boxes are running NetBSD 4.0  I successfully built a toolchain for ARM using the `build.sh` script, and built a binary for the platform.  However my luck with MIPS was not as successful.

Comment: What error do you get on the MIPS side - is it at build or run time?
What is the target CPU - Big/Little endian 32/64 bit?